# Product sale price is not shown on post pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, price, visual-composer

As i wrote in the title, i can't view the sale_price in post page but only regular price. Instead the sale_price is shown in woocommerce product page, category page etc.

Anybody could help me?

thanks a lot

[sale_price is not shown in post page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWDvS.jpg)

Comment: Please add some info about the tools or product you're using

Comment: I'm working with visual composer (https://visualcomposer.io/) that is included in wordpress template "fashiro tool". That problem appears when i insert a woo widget (product) in a post page.

Comment: I solved the problem with a simple plugin update. The plugin is Woocommerce All Discount power by Orion.